# ThreadPool and corrupted data

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, race-condition

I have a program that receives a volume of data that needs to be processed and stored in 5 different objects (MyContainer). I introduced ThreadPool so that data is processed by these objects simultaneously. Here is my code:

```
public class DataReader
{
     ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
     public void handleData(Data myData)
     {
         HashMap<MyContainer, List<String>> containerMap = someObj.getMyContainerMap();

         for (MyContainer myContainer : containerMap.keySet())
         {
              List<String> sources = containerMap.get(tContainer);

              for(String s : sources)
              {
                   if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(myData.source))
                   {
                        myContainer.setData(myData);
                        pool.submit(myContainer);
                        break;
                    }
               }    
           }
     }
}
```

MyContainer object looks like this:

```
public class MyContainer implements Runnable
{
    private int containerID;

    private Collection c1;
    private Collection c2;
    private Collection c3;
    private Collection c4;
    private Collection c5;

    private volatile Data dataToProcess;
    public void run()
    {
        addData();
    }

    public void setData(Data data)
    {
         dataToProcess = data;
    }



public void addData()
    {
         if (containerID == someConstantID1)
         {
           processDataForCol1(dataToProcess);
         }
         else if (containerID == someConstantID2)
         {
           processDataForCol2(dataToProcess);
         }        
         else if (containerID == someConstantID3)
         {
            processDataForCol3(dataToProcess);
         }
         else if (containerID == someConstantID4)
         {
            .....so on
         }

    }
}
```

The `processDataForColX()` method has its own processing logic that not same for each of 5 MyContainer objects. It's fairly complicated logic and i tried to simplify as much as i can without loosing a flow.

In short, same piece of information needs to be processed by 5 MyContainer objects. Initially it was done in sequential order, one MyContainer object was receiving data, processing, returning and next MyContainer object was processing same data. Now the amount of data increased and simultaneous processing is necessary.

My problem is that data I set with setData() is messed up, and each of 5 objects contains corrupted data.  Is this a race condition?  How is it possible?

Comment: Write a complete example to demonstrate your problem. Given the level of detail you presented here, anything is possible.

Comment: You haven't shared enough information.  We need to see what each `addDataObjX()` method does and what's actually being set.  It's possible that there's a race condition, but that cannot be determined via your post.  Please also post what you mean by "messed up" along with expected values vs actual values.

Comment: i apologize for not being clear in my initial post. I edited just now. Please let me know if it's still not clear. addDataObjX() is processDataForColX(), is converting dataToProcess into another object that is stored in ColX.

Comment: same data (myData) is read by 5 different *MyContainer* objects but processed into diff Collections. In *processDataForColX()* i only read parameters of *dataToProcess* through get methods and put them into objects. None of *processDataForColX()* try to modify data. I believe that each of myContainer objects have its own copy of *myData*. 'Messed up' means that *myData* parameter *getDate()* is wrong, keywords have an extra characters.

Comment: Date parameter of *MyData* object is reset to '12/31/1969 19:00:00 0', as an example of corrupted data.